# Sufficient conditions for differentiability of multivariate functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**Claim:** If a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ has partial derivatives in a neighborhood $D$ of $(x_0,y_0)$, and if these are continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$

**Proof:** As long as $(x,y)\in D$ we have

$$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)+f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)$$

Now applying the mean value theorem gives us, for some $z\in(x_0,x)$ and $w\in(y_0,y)$

$$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=f'_x(z,y)(x-x_0)+f'_y(x_0,w)(y-y_0)$$

Let $E(x,y)=f'_x(z,y)(x-x_0)+f'_y(x_0,w)(y-y_0)-f'_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)-f'_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$

Then, $$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+f'_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f'_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)+E(x,y)$$

All we have left to see is that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)}\frac{E(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}=0$$

By continuity of the partial derivatives for any $\varepsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x_0-x|<\delta$ and $|y_0-y|<\delta$ we have $|f'_x(x,y)-f'_x(x_0,y_0)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $|f'_y(x,y)-f'_y(x_0,y_0)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Therefore, if $|x-x_0|<\min\{\delta,\varepsilon\}$ and $|y-y_0|<\min\{\delta,\varepsilon\}$ then $|E(x,y)|=|f_x'(z,y)(x-x_0)+f'_y(x_0,w)(y-y_0)-f'_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)-f'_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)|<\frac12\varepsilon h + \frac12\varepsilon k<\frac12\varepsilon\varepsilon+\frac12\varepsilon\varepsilon=\varepsilon^2$

**Problem:** How can we see that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)}\frac{E(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}=0$$

That is, how can we  see that the error $E$ tends to zero faster that the distance betwee $(x,y)$ and $(x_0,y_0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $E$ can be written as
$$E(x,y)=\bigl(f_x(z,y)-f_x(x_0,y_0)\bigr)(x-x_0)+\bigl(f_y(x_0,w)-f_y(x_0,y_0)\bigr)(y-y_0)\ .$$
It follows that
$$\eqalign{{|E(x,y)|\over|{\bf z}-{\bf z}_0|}&\leq \bigl|f_x(z,y)-f_x(x_0,y_0)\bigr|{|x-x_0|\over|{\bf z}-{\bf z}_0|}+\bigl|f_y(x_0,w)-f_y(x_0,y_0)\bigr|{|y-y_0|\over|{\bf z}-{\bf z}_0|}\cr
&\leq \bigl|f_x(z,y)-f_x(x_0,y_0)\bigr|+\bigl|f_y(x_0,w)-f_y(x_0,y_0)\bigr|\ .\cr}$$
Here the right hand side tends to $0$ when ${\bf z}:=(x,y)\to{\bf z}_0:=(x_0,y_0)$, because the points $(z,y)$ and $(w,x_0)$ then tend to $(x_0,y_0)$ as well.