# Check differentiability of $f(x,y)=y\sin\frac{1}{x}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given , $f(x,y)=y\sin\frac{1}{x}$ when $x\ne0$ and $f(0,0)=0$ . Investigate differentiability at $(0,0)$ .

I've found that it is continuous at $(0,0)$ and the partial derivatives $f_x=0$  $\forall (x,y)$ and $f_y=\begin{cases}
\sin\frac1x & \text{ if } x\ne0\\ 
1 & \text{ if } x= 0
\end{cases}.$

For differentiability it is sufficient to show that both partial derivatives exist and one of them(confused between "both continuous" Or "one of them") is continuous about some neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ .

Now, I'm stuck. Please help how to think.

**EDIT**

$f(0,y)=y$

Comment: How is $f(0,y)$ defined when $y \ne 0$?

Comment: edited !. @GNUSupporter

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853215/sufficient-conditions-for-differentiability-of-multivariate-functions see here

Comment: @Martin , Is $f_x=0$ $\forall ( x,y)$ correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited in response to Did and PrithiviRaj's comments.)

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_x (0,0) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0\sin\frac1h - 0}{h} = 0
\end{aligned} \\
\begin{aligned}
f_y (0,0) &= \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k} \\
&= \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{k - 0}{k} = 1
\end{aligned}
$$

In the [definition of differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1405795/290189), approach the point $(0,0)$ via the curve $y = x^2$ to see that the limit
$$ \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(h,k) - f(0,0) - 0 \cdot h - 1 \cdot k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \tag{*} \label1$$
can't be defined.  Take $k = h^2$.

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \frac{f(h,h^2)-f(0,0)-h^2}{\sqrt{h^2+h^4}}
    &= \frac{h^2 (\sin \frac{1}{h} - 1)}{\sqrt{h^2+h^4}} \\
    &= \frac{\sin\frac{1}{h} - 1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{h^2}}}
  \end{aligned}
  \tag{$h\ne0$}
  \label{df1}
\end{equation}

Observe that the denominator $\sqrt{1+1/h^2} \to 1$ as $h \to 0$, but
the limit of $\sin(1/h)$ is undefined.
  To see this,

- take $h_n = 1/(n\pi)$ so that $h_n\to0$ and $\sin(1/h_n) = 0$; but
- take $h'_n = 1/((2n+1/2)\pi)$ so that $h'_n\to0$ and $\sin(1/h'_n) = 1$.

Hence \eqref{1} is undefined, and $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: but , it is sufficient not necessary , if $f_y$ and $f_x$ are not continuous , then $ f $ can be differentiable.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for pointing my mistakes out.  Sorry for that.  I'm rewriting my answers.

Comment: Could not make any sense for your answer ! Explain it ? @GNUSupporter

Comment: @PrithiviRaj I've chosen the curve $y = x^2$ by experience.  The logic is that (1) Differentiability implies existence of directional derivatives (2) Directional derivatives can be defined by a parametrization along a curve.  (3) My arg: there exists some curve at which the directional derivative can't be defined, so it's not differentiable.  You may want to see the [wiki page of directional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) (Notation and Definition).

Comment: "Directional derivatives" are limits along straight lines, not along other curves.

Comment: @Did Thanks your for comment.  I would like to draw your attention to the example "directional derivative along a curve" in [a lecture notes from Harvard](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_summer_06/handouts/directional.pdf).

Comment: @GNUSupporter , Is this true ,if directional derivatives do not exist , then it ($f$)can't be differentiable ?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then all directional derivatives at $x$ exists.  I'm showing its contrapositive form.

Comment: okay! , thanks! , now it is clear, nice approach.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Seems quite idiosyncratic to me. Interestingly (and not very surprisingly), the wiki page you linked to, stays on the usual practice of calling directional derivatives, derivatives in a... direction.

Comment: @Did In the [Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Notation) part, it's said the vector "v is a parameterization of a curve".

Comment: Indeed, and since v is constant, the "curve" one obtains is... a straight line.

Comment: @Did Thanks for explaining this.  If I understand you correctly, your point is the formula $$\nabla_{\bf v} f({\bf x}) = \nabla f({\bf x}) \cdot {\bf v}$$ for differentiable $f$ at $x$ takes *constant* ${\bf v}$.  I've edited my answer so as to use the definition of differentiability.

Comment: One way to define differentiability is that the derivative along any differentiable curve is equal to the dot product of the gradient and the tangent vector along the curve.  (In this way, the $\mathbf{v}$ need not be constant, and in fact it is important, if this condition is to be sufficient, that the curve need not be a line, as the example of $y^3/x$ shows.)  So along $y=x^2$, you could take $\lim_{h\to0}(f(h,h^2)-f(0,0))/h = \lim_{h\to0}h\sin(1/h)$, which is not $(0,1)\cdot(1,0)=0$ (in fact the limit is undefined).